# Почему при переносе вопроса метка на английском?

Tags: дефект, поддержка, локализация

При появлении [вопроса](/revisions/2488/1) он имел метку [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) вместо [обсуждение](/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%81%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5). Получается, при переносе не срабатывает автоматическая синонимизация?

Comment: Да, давно уже замечено. Похоже, там используется другой механизм. Не думаю, что это реальная проблема — вопрос всегда переносит конкретный человек и он может исправить метки.

Comment: Я вот тоже аналогичное [обнаружил](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/4063/176217).